# How can I read a QList of QPair from a file in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyside2

I'm trying to read a file written from C++ using Qt 5. The C++ code to read the file (much simplified) is:

```
QFile file("MyFile");
file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
QDataStream in(&file);

QList<QPair<QString, QByteArray>> outList;
in >> outList;
if (!outList.isEmpty())
{
...
```

But it seems like `QList` and `QPair` aren't available in PySide2. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Why do not you use standard python containers in this case I would suggest a list of tuple or a 2d list.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, but it would be easier with a sample of the content of "MyFile", can you show 5 lines here ?